# How can I select a particular element in dynamically-generated markup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jinja2

I'm trying to call a function on a `<div>` block inside of `<li>`, and I'm a little bit confused on how to specify that specific div, since they are auto-generated by a jinja for loop (meaning I can generate IDs, but I don't know which specific ones are present from the get-go). I also want to call a function that will modify one of them when the button inside the said  is pressed. How should I use `getelementbyid()` in this case? Would it be possible to pass in an ID as a parameter?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post to provide more information. We don't work with hypotheticals here. Be sure to explain in detail how you'd determine which element is "one of them".

Comment: I think just add a unique Id while generating it dynamically and then later use it with getElementById()

Comment: without your coding, help will be difficult...imagine you have to answer to your question....